# What is the alternative to getActionView() before API level11 in android?

Tags: android-actionbar, android

`getActionView()` for action bar was introduced in `API 11`, If I want backward compatibility what is the alternative for `getActionView()` ?

e.g.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar_menu, menu);

   final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuitem);
   item.getActionView() //Works from API level 11

   return true;
}
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to set click listener on the actionItemLayout, for that I need to get reference to the actionView.

Comment: please also provide your menu.xml .AFAIK actionView and actionLayout are both introudce in API 11, so there is no sense in having a compatible `getActionView()`.

Comment: Ah.. yeah, just checked, even actionLayout was introduced in API 11, damn so this question makes no sense now, Thank you. I will delete this question.

Comment: good luck. and use `ActionBarSherlock`:)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For backwards compatibility you can use either `ActionBarCompat` or `ActionBarScherlock`. In both cases you can use the method `getActionView().` You have to be sure that the import, in the first case is from the compatibility library (    `android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat`). If
you  use `ActionBarSherlock` you have to `import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem`. Then you should be ok using  `item.getActionView()`.

Old

<strike>Since August 2013, and I pray people down-voting to take a look. You have to be sure that the OP's question date import, Android introduced in the first case is from the compatibility library ( ActionBarCompactandroid.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat). Even though If you use ActionBarSherlock is still a valid choice, an option is moving towards ActionBarCompact.</strike>

So another option is to use it, and of course, all the importsyou have to came from the support library, e.g. android.supportimport com.v4actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItemCompatMenuItem. Then you should be ok using item.getActionView().

Answer (score 86):

You can use [MenuItemCompat.getActionView(MenuItem menuItem)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html#getActionView%28android.view.MenuItem%29) from the support library to get the action view on pre 11 API.

Answer (score 54):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
  MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
  SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
  // Configure the search info and add any event listeners
  ...
  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html for details

Comment: Super! I spend 2 hours to find this :P