# Text on Actionbar icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, popupwindow

Im trying to achieve some thing like Facebook `ActionBar`. I want to display `notification` count on the `ActionBar`, and when the user clicks on the icon, a pop-window opens and shows a custom list.

Im using API level 9 for my project and support lib v7 for the actionbar.

Any one got any clue on this..Help appreciated

Thanks in advance

Happy coding

Comment: Looking for https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Raghunandan. But I don't know how to use a custom view for actionbar. I would like to work on the pop-window.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288989/how-to-get-text-on-an-actionbar-icon. search on stackvoverflow you will find many similar nes

Comment: @Raghunandan I have already tried all thos. As I mentioned, Im using API level 9 for my app. So getActionView() wont work. Do you have an alternate for this method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641183/what-is-the-alternative-to-getactionview-before-api-level11-in-android. again search on stackoverflow there is an alternative. Why don't you search on stackpverflow you have many similar posts

Comment: I tried looking into some of the blogs and developer site. I tried creating my own Action provider. But ended up in some issue. stackoverflow.com/questions/21646371/actionbar-menu-remains-in-display-on-backkey-press